# 'GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT' error on Raspberry Pi while installing OpenCV

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to create a barcode scanner from a usb camera for Raspberry Pi. I used the tutorial on this site to install OpenCV on the Pi:(https://gist.github.com/rodrigobaron/072a85460e46c48e3bee24fe140b9fdb).

After I used the make command (the third to last step of the tutorial), the following error occurred:

```
error: 'GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT' was not declared in this scope
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It is important to note that I used the simple "make" command rather than "make -j4" as the "j4" option allows it to work on all four cores of the raspberry pi, and it is suggested to eliminate "-j4" if an error occurs.

Upon searching for what caused this issue, I have discovered that it may be due to OPEN_GL support not needing to be enabled, or it might also be caused by an error in the header files.  I have not determined how to re-write the make file to eliminate OPEN_GL support, nor do I feel comfortable altering the header files without good cause.  I would appreciate any advice on fixing the issue as I feel I have exhausted my options. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling OPENGL `cmake` parameters (`-DWITH_OPENGL=OFF`) should fix the problem. i.e.

```
cmake -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=OFF -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to go to line 3229 and just comment that line out.  It will build then.

This may not be the best method, but it worked for me..my file looks like this.

> opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_Qt.cpp

```
void OpenGlViewPort::initializeGL()
{
    //glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}
```